# What is the grammar in 見て見ない?

Tags: grammar

I saw 見て見ない used in the sense of "not to see", e.g.:

見て見ないふりをして通り過ぎた. (He passed by pretending not to see me.)

What is the grammar behind this form?

I thought it is Verb+て + Verb, but both verbs are the same (unless they are used in different meanings?). It's not　Verb+て+みる (since the meaning would be completely different). And it's not a standalone word, since the dictionary does not mention it (except in examples).

Also, what's the difference with 見てない? And can it be used in affirmative (見て見る) to mean "to see"?

Comment: Your example doesn't have 見て見ない in it...? I guess perhaps it just didn't get copied over completely? Some dictionaries do have it, though in an older form. https://jpdb.io/search?q=%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A6%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%AC%E3%81%B5%E3%82%8A&lang=english#a

Comment: Thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a variant of the set phrase [見て見ぬふりをする](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A6%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%AC%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#jn-214126). The closest expression in English seems to be [*to turn a blind eye to sth*](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E8%A6%8B%E9%80%83%E3%81%99/#je-73103).

Breaking down the phrase, it is 見て＋見ぬふりをする=*see and pretend not to see*, meaning *to overlook*.

---

Typical examples:

1. 悪事を見て見ないふりをする - overlook (someone's) wrong doing
2. 困っている人を見て見ぬふりをする - overlook (someone) having a trouble (= do not offer help)

Comment: "turn a blind eye to " means "to overlook someone's wrong doing" or "ignore a bad situation". Whereas, "pretend not to see" includes more general meanings. If I see someone walking down the street and don't want to talk to them I can "pretend not to see them"  but "turn a blind eye to them" would not be an appropriate usage. Do the phrases discussed here encompass all meanings?

Comment: @user3856370 I think basically it shares the point, too. Not saying hello to someone because you don't want to won't be typically described with 見て見ぬふりをする.